# Android Widget does not update

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a simple android widget with a single text view. 
I extend **AppWidgetProvider** class, widget information xml - appwidget-provider..., also updated my manifest file as per document provided on android website. 
I also set a`ndroid:updatePeriodMillis to 1800020 (~30 minutes).`

When I place widget on screen all the code under **onUpdate** method fires for the first time. But after **1800020 milliseconds**, the onUpdate doesn't called again. My widget does not update afterwards. Am I missing something with it?

I extend AppWidgetProvider as follow,

```
public class Testwidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
int COUNT = 0;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Log.d("WIDGET", "====================== UPDATED ======================");
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for(int _i=0; _i<appWidgetIds.length; _i++){
        int _widId = appWidgetIds[_i];

        COUNT+=1;

        RemoteViews _views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
        _views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvCount,String.valueOf(COUNT));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(_widId, _views);
    }
}
}
```

My Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="Testwidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo"></meta-data>
    </receiver>
```

Appwidget Provider

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="272dp" android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1800020" android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlayout">

</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Provide some code what have you tried?

Comment: can you try 1800 for update? and see what happens.

Comment: what is android:updatePeriodMillis? Is it Milliseconds? If yes then 30 minutes = 1800000 milliseconds. Google also shows the same in "30 minutes to milliseconds"

Comment: 1800 is not working, I am trying with 180000.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the correct number for miliseconds.

But there is no guarantee that the update will happen at exactly this time interval - it could be delayed by the OS (from the documentation: "The actual update is not guaranteed to occur exactly on time with this value")

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using any service it will be update after the miliseconds you have defined, to use service or complete refernce how widget works look [here.](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Minimum of update seconds is 1800000 (30 minutes). From there on the counter is set back to 0 so you have to wait another 30 minutes. Look at the [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html) Pawan leaved behind.